# Аналог события OnAdminListDisplay для интерфейса пользователя?

Tags: битрикс

Привет!
В битриксе есть событие вывода списка элементов в административном разделе - `OnAdminListDisplay`, но нигде не упоминается об аналогичном событии для пользовательского интерфейса. Где можно его найти? Или как обойтись, в случае, если такого аналога не существует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В битриксе интерфейс пользователя основан на компонентах, в них можно использовать файл result_modifier.php для модификации данных, [подробнее в доке](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2830).

Существуют так же события вызывающиеся в процессе выполнения страницы:

- OnPageStart
- OnBeforeProlog
- OnProlog
- OnEpilog
- OnAfterEpilog
- OnBeforeEndBufferContent
- OnBeforeRestartBuffer

[подробнее](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/#page)

Comment: То есть, если я правильно понял, чтобы, к примеру, добавить кнопку на панель списка элементов на странице (в пользовательском интерфейсе) мне можно создать свой обработчик события OnPageStart? Или пойти другим путем - сделать собственный компонент и внедрить его в код стандартного шаблона lists.list ?

Comment: Кстати, может подскажете, как добраться до элементов (кнопок) панели действий над списком элементов через файл result_modifier.php ? Правильно ли было бы в result_modifier.php добавлять "на лету" свою кнопку в $arResult для последующего отображения в шаблоне??